# How can I print a string from one criteria, up until another criteria is met?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, parsing

```py
criteria_1 = x
criteria_2 = y

raw = parser.from_file(MIPR_File_Path)
info = raw['content']

words = info.split()
for i,w in enumerate(words):
    if w == criteria_1:
        print(words + 1) + ...
```

What do I need to replace "..." with so that I can print all of the strings up until criteria_2 is met?

Answer (score 2):

You can add another statement:

```
if criteria_2: break
```

This will end the for loop without printing any more words.

Comment: Where do I add that line into?

Comment: Either before or after the print statement, depending on whether you still want to print the last word after the criteria is met. But generally it should be added into the first if statement.